# What's the difference between extending a class and writing a plugin for a class in Extjs 3.4?

Tags: extjs

I need to add a image upload function to extjs `htmlEditor`, and I searched the web and found that 2 different solutions are out there. One is to use plugins arrays, in which are the plugin classes extending the `util.Observable` class(and to make things even confused, they all contain something called `MidasCommand`, what is this anyway it's not in the documentation), the other is writing a extending class for `form.htmlEditor`.

Can someone please explain which should I choose and why, and also what about `Ext.override` and `Ext.extend`? Are they the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the difference between extending and plugins is:

Plugins are reusable. If you need the extension code only once, then a plugin would be over-engineerd somehow. With plugins you can have a single source for extending many classes.

`Ext.override` don't create new classes, but modify an existing class. `Ext.extend` creates a new class.

Regarding your editor, I'm afraid I cannot help you. I've found [Midas Spec](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/editor/midas-spec.html). Seems that this hasn't been developed further, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks hgoebl, I've written a extended htmleditor class, overrided method `createToobar` and added a few newly defined methods, it worked well.

Comment: @Evelyn1986 congratulations! Not very easy until all works, eh? Don't forget to destroy the things you have created: `beforedestroy` and `destroy` events. But it looks like you don't need it in your case, but it's often forgotten.